# Global is not defined when trying to use `interweave` in an `Electron-React-Typescript-Webpack` app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

In my `Electron-React-Typescript-Webpack` app I'm now trying to use `interweave`in a `tsx` page:

```
import Interweave, { Markup } from 'interweave';

function App_B() {

    return (
      <div id="outer-container" className='outer-container'>

        <div id="my-content" className="plaintext">
          <Interweave content="This string contains <b>HTML</b> and will safely be rendered!" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I get this error: `Global is not defined`
[image]

How to solve the problem?
Looking forward to your kind help

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" putting in the `HTML` page linked to the `tsx` page this line:

```
<script> const global = globalThis; </script>
```

Why did this happen with `interweave` and not with other libraries I'm using?